# CORS error on AWS S3 bucket upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have my AWS S3 bucket CORS configuration set up as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:5000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And making a signed upload request in the browser:

```
function upload_file(file, signed_request, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signed_request);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            $('#photo').css('background-image', "url('"+url+"')");
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(err) {
        alert("Could not upload file.", err);
    };
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

But both chrome and firefox throw a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header not set error. Specifically in firefox: "(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

Comment: You'll have to do the upload from a server, not from the client from what I know about CORS.

Comment: From the articles I've read you can direct upload to an S3 bucket. I'm running node on the server so want to avoid a pass through upload...

Comment: You are correct, though I've only done it with an angular module (I remember now). My bad.

Comment: I've had no trouble uploading to a bucket directly as OliverJ90 has mentioned. The only CORS settings I have involved server to server as Christopher Marshall has said.

Comment: Is "localhost" a valid origin with CORS?  It seems a little meaningless, and wouldn't surprise me if it is not.  You might try accessing your machine using `http://lvh.me:5000/` which is a test domain that resolves to 127.0.0.1 just like `localhost`, while appearing to be a real domain name, to see if it makes the browser happier.

Comment: Are you sending your secret from the client via `signed_request`? If so, don't do that.

Comment: @aug2uag no the secret is only accessed on the server

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot worked! Thanks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, helped resolve my cors issue

Answer (score 2):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header does not allow wildcards. It must contain actual header names.

Look at preflight request in your network tab.The values in `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header must be included as `AllowedHeader`.

Comment: Are you sure? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors
`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`